# Error in initialize when creating a class dynamically

Tags: ruby, class, methods, initialization, instance

I receive some paramters at the command line. The first one of them tells me what kind of uby object I must create to perform de desired action. I store this parameter in `@entity` and then I create an instance of this class by doing

```
entity_class = "EmeraldFW::#{@entity.capitalize}".split('::').inject(Object) {|o,c| o.const_get c}
entity_instance = entity.new(@arguments,@options)
entity_instance.execute_command
```

I am geting an error when I try to create one of these instances, say Project.

My project class is

```
module EmeraldFW

  class Project < EmeraldFW::Entity

    def self.initialize(args,opts)
      @valid_option = [ :language, :test, :database, :archetype ]
      super(args,opts)
    end
.
.
.
```

and my class Entity is

```
module EmeraldFW

  class Entity

    attr_accessor :entity_type, :valid_commands

    def self.initialize(args,opts)
      @args = args
      @opts = clean_option(opts)
    end

.
.
.
```

My error is

```
/home/edvaldo/software/github/emeraldfw21/lib/emeraldfw.rb:41:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
```

and I don't know why this is happening. As you may see, initialize receives two arguments and I gave it two arguments, as required.

Maybe because I'm looking at this for a long time, but I just can't see the reason. Would somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your `initialize` method is written as "class" method (class' singleton method), whereas it should be an instance method. Due to that fact original `initialize` method which you are calling with `new`:

```
entity_instance = entity.new(@arguments,@options)
```

takes no arguments.

To resolve the issue ***remove*** `self.` parts from `self.initialize` method definitions.

---

```
class Foo
  def initialize(bar, baz)
    @bar = bar
    @baz = baz
  end
end

Foo.new(:bar, :baz)
#=> #<Foo:0x007fa6d23289a0 @bar=:bar, @baz=:baz>
```